# Pyspark - How can I restructure my output in the following format?

Tags: for-loop, pyspark, output

I have two tables as shown below :

Table 1 -

[image]

Table 2 -

[image]

I would like my output to be like the following table with the following calculation on loop until all weeks on table 2 has gone through all days of table 1:

table3(week1_1) = table2(**week1**) * table1(**day1**_ratio)

table3(week1_2) = table2(**week1**) * table1(**day2**_ratio)

[image]

How can this be done?

All help is appreciated!!

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

> Written in scala, but can be ported to pyspark with minimal change

### Load the input

```scala
   val table1 = Seq(
      ("o1", "i1", 1, 0.6),
      ("o1", "i1", 2, 0.4)
    ).toDF("outlet", "item", "day", "ratio")
    table1.show(false)
    /**
      * +------+----+---+-----+
      * |outlet|item|day|ratio|
      * +------+----+---+-----+
      * |o1    |i1  |1  |0.6  |
      * |o1    |i1  |2  |0.4  |
      * +------+----+---+-----+
      */

    val table2 = Seq(
      ("o1", "i1", 4, 5, 6, 8)
    ).toDF("outlet", "item", "week1", "week2", "week3", "week4")
    table2.show(false)
    /**
      * +------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |outlet|item|week1|week2|week3|week4|
      * +------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |o1    |i1  |4    |5    |6    |8    |
      * +------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      */
```

### User spark functions

```scala
    table1.join(table2, Seq("outlet", "item"))
      .groupBy("outlet", "item")
      .pivot("day")
      .agg(
        first($"week1" * $"ratio").as("week1"),
        first($"week2" * $"ratio").as("week2"),
        first($"week3" * $"ratio").as("week3"),
        first($"week4" * $"ratio").as("week4")
      ).show(false)

    /**
      * +------+----+-------+-------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+-------+
      * |outlet|item|1_week1|1_week2|1_week3           |1_week4|2_week1|2_week2|2_week3           |2_week4|
      * +------+----+-------+-------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+-------+
      * |o1    |i1  |2.4    |3.0    |3.5999999999999996|4.8    |1.6    |2.0    |2.4000000000000004|3.2    |
      * +------+----+-------+-------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+------------------+-------+
      */
```

### In python

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 table1.join(table2, ['outlet', 'item'])       
.groupBy("outlet", "item")       
.pivot("day")       
.agg(         
F.first(df.week1 * df.ratio).alias("week1"),         
F.first(df.week2 * df.ratio).alias("week2"),         
F.first(df.week3 * df.ratio).alias("week3"),         
F.first(df.week4 * df.ratio).alias("week4")       
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: is there a possibility of getting this in pyspark? I tried it but it wasn't successful. Will really help if you can!

Comment: ref- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

Comment: try this- ```from pyspark.sql import functions as F table1.join(table2, ['outlet', 'item'])       .groupBy("outlet", "item")       .pivot("day")       .agg(         F.first(df.week1 * df.ratio).alias("week1"),         F.first(df.week2 * df.ratio).alias("week2"),         F.first(df.week3 * df.ratio).alias("week3"),         F.first(df.week4 * df.ratio).alias("week4")       ).show(truncate=False)```. haven't executed on pyspark, but it should work